# getLastLocation google service

Tags: java, android

I developed an app to get current location however I got nothing for the location, I also tried the solution in [GoogleService failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize) but it didn't worked for me.

here is my main activity:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class GetLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements     GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,     GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_location);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

//        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
//                .addApi(Drive.API)
//                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
//                .build();

    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
    //if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
   // }

}


protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_get_location, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        TextView mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLatitudeText);
        TextView mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLongitudeText);
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    TextView mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLatitudeText);
    TextView mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLongitudeText);
    mLatitudeText.setText("onConnectionSuspended");
    mLongitudeText.setText("onConnectionSuspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    TextView mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLatitudeText);
    TextView mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLongitudeText);
    mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(connectionResult));
    mLongitudeText.setText("onConnectionFailed");

    }
   }
```

and here is my `Logcat`:

```
12-29 01:16:41.170 14919-14919/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
12-29 01:16:41.170 14919-14919/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
12-29 01:16:41.200 14919-14919/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
12-29 01:16:41.230 14919-14919/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-29 01:16:41.230 14919-14919/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-29 01:16:41.240 14919-14919/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
12-29 01:16:41.250 14919-14919/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-29 01:16:41.250 1358-1791/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.timesavii.getlocation appid=10043 user=0: from pid 14919
12-29 01:16:41.250 1358-1791/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 14857:com.timesavii.getlocation/u0a43 (adj 0): stop com.timesavii.getlocation
12-29 01:16:41.280 1358-1394/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel '683d475 com.timesavii.getlocation/com.timesavii.getlocation.GetLocation (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
12-29 01:16:41.280 1358-1394/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '683d475 com.timesavii.getlocation/com.timesavii.getlocation.GetLocation (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-29 01:16:41.280 1358-1596/system_process D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 2
12-29 01:16:41.280 1358-1596/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{683d475 u0 com.timesavii.getlocation/com.timesavii.getlocation.GetLocation}
12-29 01:16:41.280 1358-1596/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '683d475 com.timesavii.getlocation/com.timesavii.getlocation.GetLocation (server)'
12-29 01:16:41.300 1358-1791/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{afb69f2 u0 com.timesavii.getlocation/.GetLocation t91}: app died, no saved state
12-29 01:16:41.310 14919-14919/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-29 01:16:41.320 1358-1789/system_process W/ActivityManager: Spurious death for ProcessRecord{9193003 0:com.timesavii.getlocation/u0a43}, curProc for 14857: null
12-29 01:16:41.390 1688-1978/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-29 01:16:41.390 1688-1978/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe12b8480, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-29 01:16:42.200 14928-14928/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
12-29 01:16:42.200 14928-14928/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
12-29 01:16:42.210 14932-14932/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
12-29 01:16:42.210 14932-14932/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
12-29 01:16:42.240 14928-14928/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
12-29 01:16:42.270 14928-14928/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-29 01:16:42.270 14928-14928/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-29 01:16:42.280 14932-14932/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
12-29 01:16:42.290 14928-14928/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
12-29 01:16:42.310 14928-14928/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
12-29 01:16:42.340 14932-14932/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-29 01:16:42.340 14932-14932/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-29 01:16:42.350 14932-14932/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
12-29 01:16:42.370 14932-14932/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-29 01:16:42.380 1358-1370/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.timesavii.getlocation/.GetLocation} from uid 0 on display 0
12-29 01:16:43.560 1358-1488/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 14857 uid 10043
12-29 01:16:43.560 14928-14928/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-29 01:16:43.560 1358-1371/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.windowGainedFocus(com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient, android.os.IBinder, int, int, int, android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo, com.android.internal.view.IInputContext) from InputMethodManagerService.java:2177 waiters=0 for 2.010s
12-29 01:16:43.560 1688-1688/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox I/Choreographer: Skipped 128 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-29 01:16:43.590 1358-1372/system_process W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=int com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(android.app.IApplicationThread, int, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String, android.service.voice.IVoiceInteractionSession, com.android.internal.app.IVoiceInteractor, android.os.IBinder, java.lang.String, int, int, android.app.ProfilerInfo, android.app.IActivityManager$WaitResult, android.content.res.Configuration, android.os.Bundle, boolean, int, android.app.IActivityContainer, com.android.server.am.TaskRecord) from ActivityStackSupervisor.java:946 waiters=0 for 750ms
12-29 01:16:43.590 14932-14932/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-29 01:16:43.650 1861-1861/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/LocationOracleImpl: Best location was null
12-29 01:16:43.700 1861-14948/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr: Starting hotword detection.
12-29 01:16:43.730 1861-14950/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.u@f8a6cc8
12-29 01:16:43.740 1042-1708/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
12-29 01:16:43.740 1042-14952/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xf3700000 ready to run
12-29 01:16:43.770 1861-14950/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.u@f8a6cc8
12-29 01:16:43.770 1861-2330/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.u@f8a6cc8
12-29 01:16:43.770 1861-14950/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error -4 during AudioRecord native read
12-29 01:16:43.770 14953-14953/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-29 01:16:43.780 1358-1738/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 14953:com.timesavii.getlocation/u0a43 for activity com.timesavii.getlocation/.GetLocation
12-29 01:16:43.860 1861-2333/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr: Stopping hotword detection.
12-29 01:16:43.980 1861-14948/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/HotwordRecognitionRnr: Hotword detection finished
12-29 01:16:44.020 1688-1978/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe12a3690
12-29 01:16:44.060 1861-1871/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3331(258KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 80ms total 330ms
12-29 01:16:44.070 14953-14953/com.timesavii.getlocation W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.timesavii.getlocation-1/lib/x86_64
12-29 01:16:44.100 14953-14953/com.timesavii.getlocation I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
12-29 01:16:44.100 14953-14953/com.timesavii.getlocation I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
12-29 01:16:44.100 14953-14953/com.timesavii.getlocation E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
12-29 01:16:44.100 14953-14953/com.timesavii.getlocation E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
12-29 01:16:44.130 14953-14969/com.timesavii.getlocation E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
12-29 01:16:44.230 14953-14963/com.timesavii.getlocation I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15526(955KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 52% free, 1833KB/3MB, paused 10ms total 20ms
12-29 01:16:44.270 1030-1181/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
12-29 01:16:44.270 14953-14978/com.timesavii.getlocation D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-29 01:16:44.370 14953-14978/com.timesavii.getlocation I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-29 01:16:44.410 14953-14978/com.timesavii.getlocation W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-29 01:16:44.410 14953-14978/com.timesavii.getlocation W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f382e3bcc00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-29 01:16:44.540 1950-2017/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
12-29 01:16:44.640 1358-1370/system_process D/WifiService: acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@f597139}
12-29 01:16:44.730 1950-2017/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
12-29 01:16:44.790 1358-1377/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.timesavii.getlocation/.GetLocation: +1s30ms
12-29 01:16:45.040 1950-2017/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
12-29 01:16:45.080 1358-1791/system_process D/WifiService: releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@f597139}
12-29 01:16:54.280 14953-14969/com.timesavii.getlocation I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
12-29 01:19:27.090 1358-1371/system_process I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
12-29 01:21:29.890 1358-1369/system_process D/WifiService: acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@f597139}
12-29 01:21:29.900 1358-1488/system_process D/WifiService: releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@f597139}
```

Comment: Did you checked the option 'Access to my locaiton' from your device Settings -> Location access (option may be placed under other name in settings)? The point is that I wasn't receiving any location because of this option, after checking it, everything started to work.

Comment: Actually I am testing on an emulator, i checked the settings and it is OK. I also chekced the google maps on the emulator, and it works fine, so I think the problem is somewhere in my code.

Comment: Did you set the permision for <uses-permission `android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` ? Another thing is to enable 'Location access', then open the google maps on the emulator, and then start again your app (sugestion from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090573/locationclient-getlastlocation-always-returns-null-on-emulator#comment39971089_19968273) )

Comment: Yes I set it, and I checked with google map, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For current location u can try this code:

```
LocationManager location_manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener listner = new MyLocationListener();
            location_manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 2000, listner);
            location_manager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        StringBuilder str;


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {

            latitude = arg0.getLatitude();
            longitude = arg0.getLongitude();

            try {

                geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                if (geocoder.isPresent()) {

                    Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                    String city = returnAddress.getLocality();
                    String zipCode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();



                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: where does the getLastLocation() gets the coordinates from?

Answer (score 0):

after couple of days searching and trying different advises, this is what I found that solve my problem:

1. My AVD had not proper API installed, the AVD has to have the API with google play option.
2. The android studio can't get the location, it doesn't have the access to your laptop or PC location service. To test if the app works well and is able to get the location, we have to use tools>android>andriod device monitor, then in emulator control tab you can send the location manually to the emulator to get the location.